# Creating a Filter system for images using NextGen Gallery for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

Using the latest version of Wordpress and NextGen Gallery plugin... I'm trying to create a filter system for the images. For instance: If you click on a link called "Vacation" all the images with the tag/alt of Vacation would appear and the rest would disappear and so on. Is there a plugin I can use or does NextGen have anything built in?

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to getting this filter going? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin works: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery-powertags/

It's an extension for the NextGen plugin. Once activated, be sure to "Activate permalinks" in NextGen's Options first.

You can use the [nggpowertags] shortcode, which will show your gallery + clickable tag filters. Just be aware that images without tags will **not** show up (at least not by default). I.e, make sure all of your images are tagged.

If you don't feel like tagging all your images, you can also use the default [nggallery] shortcode and place [tagcloud] above it. This gets you roughly the same result.